# display some data from the database to datagridview

Tags: c#, ms-access

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Author='"+Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem)+"'";

reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

ex.
I select `"John"` from the comboBox.
the datagridview will show the data from the database whose `Author="John"`.
For example, there are 4 books with the same author(John), how can I display those data to datagridview?

Comment: FYI: Your script is prone to SQL Injection

Comment: Please use [_parameterized queries_](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) in your sql queries. This is an invation for [_SQL Injection_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: But, is this query _should_ get all books where their author is `John`? Are you sure your design is correct?

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Author='"+Convert.ToString(comboBox1.SelectedItem)+"'";

var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

var list = new List<string>();
while(reader.Read())
{
   list.Add(reader["Author"].ToString())
}

datagridview.DataSource = list;
```

there are many (many!) things wrong with doing it this way - but it wil properly get you on your way.

First of all - try to avoid having your GUI so "close" to the db code.
Secondly, as mentionsed, this code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

My suggestion:

```
public List<string> GetAuthors(string aurtherName)
{

  using(var con = CreateConnection()//somehow )
  {   
    var command = con.CreateCommand();

    string sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Author='@value'";
     command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", aurtherName);
     command.CommandText = sql ;

    var list = new List<string>();
    while(reader.Read())
    {
       list.Add(reader["Author"].ToString())
    }

     return list;
  }
}
```

that way you can call it like this:

```
datagridview.DataSource = GetAuthors(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```